# (C++) Can you add a direct link into a C++ program without a GUI?

Tags: c++

I was wondering if you can add a link to a website in a C++ program running in the CMD Prompt type window (No GUI)

If it's possible can some one please give me a few examples?

Answer (score 4):

You mean output text in the command prompt that the user can then click on? No, not unless the terminal supported it. Linux terminals usually autolink text that matches a URL pattern, so you could just `printf("http://stackoverflow.com/\n");` and it would be clickable, but that's up to the terminal, not your program

Answer (score 1):

When you write 'direct link' it is not clear if you mean clickable text or a means to open a url.  At any rate, command line programs usually respond to command line parameters.  Your program could open a url in the default browser in response to a command line flag.  On Windows, you could call [ShellExecute](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224816) - on other systems, `system` might be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. In Windows, for example, yes, it's entirely possible, though somewhat non-trivial. You can receive mouse events via [`ReadConsoleInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684961%28VS.85%29.aspx), so in theory it's a fairly straightforward matter of reading the input event, and if it's a mouse click over the area you've defined as a link, you direct the user to the link as you see fit -- if you want to display the web site in text mode, that's possible (though, again, *distinctly* non-trivial). If you want to start up the user's normal web browser, that's a lot simpler (normally just [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28VS.85%29.aspx) the URL).

In reality, the details get a bit ugly. You have to enable mouse input for it to work at all. `ReadConsoleInput` gives you an [`INPUT_RECORD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683499%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), which is a union of a number of different input record types, one of which is a mouse input record. By the time you get to react to a mouse click, your code is nested fairly deeply. None of it is unmanageable by any means, but unless you already have a fair amount of experience with Windows console programming, it might easily take most of a day (maybe even a bit more) before you have it working, rather than the hour or two you'd initially guess.

That, of course, is strictly for Windows -- if you ever want to port the code to another system, I'd guess there's a pretty good chance you'd be looking at a complete rewrite. For GUIs there are a fair number of cross-platform libraries, but text mode mouse operations aren't nearly so well supported.

Comment: On Unix and Mac systems, you could call `system()` or `popen()` (or if you want to go crazy and be perfect about it, use `fork()` and `exec()`, which give you lots more control) to launch a browser with the URL as a command-line parameter.  On the Mac, the command `open` will launch the user's browser if given a URL argument, so something like `std::string cmd("open '"); cmd += url; cmd += "'"; system(cmd.c_str());` might do the trick.  I don't know how to launch the user's preferred browser in Linux; it may be different for Gnome vs. KDE. P.S. *Make sure you properly escape the URL.*